# Passing control characters to c program

Tags: command-line, c

i'm trying to pass my string with special characters, but somehow my program recognize them too literally. Here is my program.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char    *str;
    char    *trim;
    char    *res;

    if (argc != 3)
        return (-1);
    str = argv[1];
    trim = argv[2];
    printf("Original string: %s\n", str);
    printf("Set of charcters to trim: %s\n", trim);
    res = ft_strtrim(str, trim);
    printf("Same string with trimed charcters: %s\n", res);
    return (0);
}
```

And this is my output.

```
$ ./test_ft_strtrim.exec "lorem \n ipsum \t dolor \n sit \t amet" "\t \n"
Original string: lorem \n ipsum \t dolor \n sit \t amet
Set of charcters to trim: \t \n
Same string with trimed charcters: lorem \n ipsum \t dolor \n sit \t amet
```

I googled all over, but i found nothing :C

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with C specific. The command line comes from the OS. 
Take the input from a file or escape it in the command line and unescape it in your program. OR use single quotes. See https://superuser.com/questions/163515/bash-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-containing-special-characters

Answer (score 0):

@tgkprog Thank's fot the link, it's works right now. All i had to do is change `"` character to single quotes and add `$` character right before the string values:

```
$ ./test_ft_strtrim.exec $'lorem \n ipsum \t dolor \n sit \t amet' $'\t \n'
Original string: lorem 
 ipsum   dolor 
 sit     amet
Set of charcters to trim: 

Same string with trimed charcters: lorem 
 ipsum   dolor 
 sit     amet
```